# Charts and gauges not rendering in Report Viewer

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report-viewer2012

I have a number of SSRS reports that contain various charts and/or gauges.  All reports had been displaying the charts and gauges correctly.  Now, none of the reports display any chart or gauge; just a blank space where the chart or gauge is supposed to appear.  Yet tables in the same reports continue to display correctly.

In between it all working correctly and when the gauges and charts stopped displaying, I had gone into Reporting Services Configuration Manager and into SQL Server Management Studio so I may have inadvertently changed something that has caused the problem.  But what?  I've spent ages trying to find a cause but no luck.

I have even created an entirely new project and created an entirely new report containing a chart and a table.  Same problem - the table displays correctly but there is just a blank space where the chart is supposed to be.

Because it is affecting all reports (even ones that I haven't touched and new ones that I create), it seems as if I have unwittingly changed some setting that is now causing Report Viewer to not display gauges and charts (but continues to display tables).

As I say, it had all been working fine.

Any suggestions as to what could cause this problem across all reports or where to look for the cause of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed SQL Server (just ran the installer in repair mode - ie, without uninstalling first) and all the gauges and charts are displaying correctly again.  I have no idea what the problem was.